# Can flutter implement iOS native iOS11 drag and drop feature?

Tags: ios, flutter

[image: Drag and Drop Feature]

I feel to do not have this characteristic at present, but I still want to hold try a state of mind to seek advice next everybody

[The Drag and Drop Demo video From Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1MWgquPXtM)

Comment: native? no. What do you want to do?

Comment: Yes, the native feature on ios11.
It can transfer data to other apps in split screen mode.

Comment: Could you give us an example? Your question is abstract for people who does not know iOS, but since we know Flutter maybe we can help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I have edited it.

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe you can use the PlatformViews feature to embed a native iOS Drag'n'drop view?

Comment: thank u for ur help